# chrome is crashing when Silverlight calling javascript method

Tags: javascript, c#, silverlight, crash

Chrome is crashing when i am trying to call a javascript method  like that :

System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("shopPopup", "text");

```
function shopPopup(param) {
        alert(param);
    }
</script>
```

javascript method is not important, i tried an other methods, the result the same.

It works on IExplorer.

Thanks for answers.